# CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation sometimes does not return UPDATE, DELETE notifications

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckfetchnotificationchange

`CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` returns INSERT operations, but UPDATE and DELETE, not always. DELETE, UPDATE worked last when I submitted app to App Store, but now not anymore. Why? I have created subscriptions like:

```
let s = CKSubscription(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: .FiresOnRecordCreation | .FiresOnRecordUpdate | .FiresOnRecordDeletion)
s.notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
subscriptionsToSave.append(s)
```

Dashboard shows  all tree triggers:

[image]

I do not use any `alertBody`, so notification is a so called silent notification, can it be the cause?

In [CloudKit Tips and Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=715) lecturer says that subscription needs APS capability for app ID turned on from the developer portal. I don't think I have, but I just want fetch notifications, push only if this works.

Background capabilities? - same

Need to set up APS environment key in app's info plist. - I guess I have it.

Comment: I have same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31108576/1646157

Comment: more in Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7288

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for those Googling, be sure to check out this thorough post on the inconsistency of notifications:

[Silent pushes not delivered to the app on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11/51759602)

I found a particularly subtle fix [that I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11/51759602#51759602).