# Alternatives to UPDATE notification that does not work

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckfetchrecordchangesopera, ckfetchnotificationchange

UPDATE notification stopped working. What workaround do you have, until Apple figures out something?

[CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation sometimes does not return UPDATE, DELETE notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103522/ckfetchnotificationchangesoperation-sometimes-not-returns-update-delete-notific)
[CloudKit push notifications on record update stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108576/cloudkit-push-notifications-on-record-update-stopped-working)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7288

My quick fix, that in every minute, and when user triggers `UIRefreshControl`, then I downloading all the records that were modified since the last update. It works. But I have a better idea in my mind, curious, what do you think. Any drawbacks.

I am thinking adding a `Change` table to the database. It will have a `recordName`, `recordType`, `changeType` fields. `changeType` could have `insert`, `update`, `delete` string values. (or int enumerations accordingly)

And I would create and observe with `CKSubscription` only the `Change` table. Always when a record is create, updated, deleted in a custom table, I would **do two things, do that action and as a second action I would make a 'log entry' into the `Change` table**. Because it is an `Insert` operation in `Change`, and insert notification seems to work, all the device would get notified. They could download the refered record.

Do you see any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a similar strategy. There are some drawbacks:

- more data (storage and transfer) usage
- limited subscription possibilities or you have to duplicate even more data.
- extra code in your app that you actually don't want to be there.

The only good solution to this problem is:

- Apple should fix it...

Comment: We have to send all together a mail at Apple's CEO and open a bug report on Apple's Bug Reporter. It's been 2 months that this bug is still there.