# CKSubscription of type CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I setup a `CKSubscription` with the following code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"RecordTypeName"
                                                                 predicate:predicate
                                                            subscriptionID:@"Subscription1"
                                                                   options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate];

CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
 [privateDatabase saveSubscription:subscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription * _Nullable subscription, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Failed to subscribe.");
     }
 }];
```

In `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` I get notified when a new record is added, but I never get notified when an existing record is updated.

I've tried updating records from both the CloudKit dashboard and from another device signed into the same account.

I'm testing on iOS 9 beta 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known bug that update notifications are not working.

[[CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation sometimes does not return UPDATE, DELETE notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103522/ckfetchnotificationchangesoperation-sometimes-not-returns-update-delete-notific][1])
[[CloudKit push notifications on record update stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108576/cloudkit-push-notifications-on-record-update-stopped-working][2])
[https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7288][3]

Comment: You won't be the first :-)

Comment: <insert outrageous amount of angry words here>


I have spent so much time on this beating my head against my monitor because I have no idea why it isnt working. 

Its relieving to know that its not my fault, but frustrating to know that I cant do anything to fix it.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer for me with my containers it seems UPDATE and DELETE notifications are working, how do you see? They might fixed it finally?!