# How to test that silent notifications are working in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cksubscription

I have a program using subscriptions with silent notification:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID == %@", CKRecordID(recordName: "ListName"))

let silentNotification = CKNotificationInfo()
silentNotification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
silentNotification.desiredKeys = ["Update"]

let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Lists", predicate: predicate, options: .FiresOnRecordUpdate)
subscription.notificationInfo = silentNotification

saveSubscription(subscription)
```

I now can see the subscription in CloudKit dashboard but, when updating the `Update` value of the record followed, my app doesn't receive a notification.

As silent notifications are based on best-effort is it normal to don't receive it immediately? I'm using the iOS simulator and would like to be able to debug my app, how can I do that when using silent notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CloudKit bug. Update notifications are still not working.

See:
[CKSubscription of type CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905152/cksubscription-of-type-cksubscriptionoptionsfiresonrecordupdate-doesnt-work)

please file a bug report at apple at https://bugreport.apple.com/
many people already have done the same, but apparently it still need more attention from Apple.